# Cannot connect to internet within WhatsApp in Android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, whatsapp-messenger

I want to use WhatsApp in PC within Android emulator. I am using the official emulator.exe within an Android Virtual Device of Android 2.3.

My PC is behind a proxy so I set the proxy in the setting of the Android emulator. I can access Google with the default browser.

I tried to use WhatsApp but after I had submit my mobile phone number, it said cannot connect.

[image: screen shot]

Please dont't recommend other 3rd party Android emulator to me because I planned to use other app with this emulator.

Comment: Can you access other websites via the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It is problem about proxy...
because proxy set in "mobile networks" does not work
so you will need "Drony app" and configure it to work with proxy.
[Download Drony](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy.drony)!

Comment: Note that the app is not available on the Play Store anymore, future readers won't be able to download and use it (you may still be able to see the entry on the Play Store if you have installed it before).